# Need to wrap a Blender 2.49 game (Using Python 2.6.2) to C++ for Steam (Using Steamworks)

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, blender, steamworks-api

how are you?
My name is Alejandro Navarro, game developer. 
I reached Steam Greenlight while ago with a Blender 2.49 game, called ARKADIANAX
(I wanted to post the link, but I need more reputation to do that)

The thing is I know nothing about coding (There is a friend helping me with this, but he couldn't help me with this part either).
Blender 2.49 uses Python 2.6.2, and the Steam API (Steamworks) Uses C++, so I need to wrap the code. I tried a lot using this wrapper:
https://github.com/Gramps/SteamworksForPython

But I can't make this work. I'm getting errors:

Python script error from controller "cont5#CONTR#2" (Those are the names of the logic bricks which are calling the steamworks.py script)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "steamworks.py", line 4, in 
    from ctypes import

The complete error is in the link I'm uploading to Mediafire together with Steamworks and Wrapper:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/h1097ag8kawg07m/Files.rar

I would be so grateful if anyone can give me a hand, I will add him to the credits of the game and I'll hang a painting of him in my house haha.

Thanks a lot for your time to read this.
Best wishes.

Comment: Do you know how old blender 2.49 is? it has now been 7 years since it was released. How much work would it be to update your game to use blender 2.77? Is it mostly logic bricks or is there a lot of python code? The age of blender 2.49 will leave you with limited help.

Answer (score 0):

While blender 2.49 uses python, it only uses the python interpreter and includes a limited subset of standard python modules, which doesn't include ctypes. You can look through the blender install to find a zip file containing the python install used - this is part of the windows install (and optionally a linux build), inside this zip file you will find the python standard modules that are included. You should be able to get a corresponding python ctypes module and add it to this, it looks like you may also need to add the sys module as well.

If you don't have any luck with that approach, you could consider getting a copy of the source code and compiling your own version of blender. When you checkout the current source code as described at [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/repository/master/) you still have the ability to checkout the 2.49 source code and build a new copy of blender 2.49 with any c/c++ modifications you add. Using blender's code for examples you can [add a c/c++ module](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) that can be accessed through blender's python interpreter and compile it into blender's binary.